# Overload += for a vector class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

When I overload the += it seems that it is only reaching the first element of the table.
Output of the main: (20,15,15) ... normally it should be (20,20,20)

This my class vecteur:

```
class vecteur{
    int tab[3];
public:
    vecteur(int = 0, int =0, int = 0);
    vecteur(const vecteur&);
    ~vecteur();
    void affiche();
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream&, const vecteur&);
    friend istream& operator>> (istream&, vecteur&);
    vecteur operator+ (const vecteur&);
    vecteur& operator++ ();
    vecteur& operator++ (int);
    vecteur& operator+= (const vecteur&);
    bool operator== (const vecteur&);
    bool operator!= (const vecteur&);
};
```

Here's the overload of the operator +=:

```
vecteur& vecteur::operator+= (const vecteur& v)
{
    tab[0] += v.tab[0];
    tab[1] += v.tab[1];
    tab[2] += v.tab[2];
    return *this;
}
```

And the main

```
int main()
{
    vecteur v1(15,15,15);
    v1 += 5;
    cout << v1;
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: vecteur::vecteur(int v1, int v2, int v3)
{
    tab[0] = v1;
    tab[1] = v2;
    tab[2] = v3;
    cout << "Constructeur de la classe de base" << endl;
}

Comment: You'll need another overload - `vecteur& operator+=(int);` to handle what you're doing

Answer (score 3):

The right hand side of this expression

```
v1 += 5;
```

needs to be converted `vecteur` (because `operator+=` takes a `const vecteur&`). That's done via implicit conversion using this constructor:

```
vecteur(int = 0, int =0, int = 0);
```

Since you only provided the first argument, the rest are defaulted to 0. And 15 + 0 gives 15 :)

Answer (score 2):

Your overload does not work for the type you are supplying:

```
vecteur& vecteur::operator+= (const vecteur& v)
{
    tab[0] += v.tab[0];
    tab[1] += v.tab[1];
    tab[2] += v.tab[2];
    return *this;
}
```

This expects a `vecteur` parameter.  `v1 += 5;` is passing an integer.

Since you declare a conversion constructor `vecteur(int = 0, int =0, int = 0);`, when you pass `5` to `+=`, what you are really passing is a `vecteur(5, 0, 0)`, which is why your second and third elements are untouched.

If you want to be able to add a scalar to every element in the `vecteur`, you'll need another overload:

```
vecteur& vecteur::operator+=(int s)
{
    tab[0] += s;
    tab[1] += s;
    tab[2] += s;
    return *this;
}
```

I would also caution against using default parameters for constructors, to avoid these types of bugs.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in this statement

```
v1 += 5;
```

at first a temporary object of type vecteur is created calling constrauctor

```
vecteur(int = 0, int =0, int = 0);
```

as

```
vecteur( 5 );
```

that is the second and the third parameters have default arguments that are equal to 0.

And this temporary object with tab[0] = 5, tab[1] = 0 and tab[2] = 0 is added to v1.

You could write

```
v1 += { 5, 5, 5 };
```

instead of

```
v1 += 5;
```

and get the result you want.:)

For example

```
int main()
{
    vecteur v1(15,15,15);
    v1 += { 5, 5, 5 };
    cout << v1;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What's happening in your code is that the operator overloading function takes another vector, rather than integer.

The integer 5 is converted into a vector using the constructor (int, int, int), with the first element equals to 5, second element equals to 0, and third element equals to 0.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't know why your program is working since you've not overloaded the += operator to work with integers (something like: `vecteur& operator+= (const int&);`) and that is the operation that you are performing (`v1 += 5;`).
But, if you try to use the += operator with an other *vecteur*, it should work.
Example:

```
vecteur v1(15,15,15);
vecteur v2(5,5,5);
v1+=v2;
cout<<v1;
//This should print 20,20,20
```

Comment: Its program works because the class has a conversion constructor.